# Is it possible to select records range from n to n+10 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'd like implement a pagination. So I just wonder whether it's possible to select records range from n to n+10 in mysql. Then I can show 10 records in page n

thanks.
Jeff Zhang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table <where clause if required> limit 10,20
```

Here n is 10 and 20 is n+10

Comment: -1 first argument is the offset, 2nd argument is the number of results, this will give 20 results.

Comment: the OP wants 10 results, your answer gives 20 results, starting from n=10.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col_name FROM your_table WHERE <conditions here> LIMIT 0, 10
```

0 = offset
10 limit

Change the offset, that does your n+10.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columns FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET n
```

Replace `columns`, `table`, and `n` with appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT n,10
```

This is correct code !

Comment: @Davood, the parameters to the limit clause cannot be dynamic, so that code is not correct as is!, if you were to say "replace n by the offset that you want, because MySQL wants to see literal numbers in its `limit` clause." That would be `correct` code.

Comment: @Johan - This is clearly pseudocode, just like the answer by Talljoe

Comment: @Ted and Davood, then the answer should say "this is pseudo code", and php comments are irrelevant because this is a pure MySQL question, you can't do a dynamic parameter for `limit` in pure MySQL.

Comment: Okay, you say right, but my code not incorrect ;) you want discovery a mistake on it ;) Good luck

Comment: @Johan - let's see...Shakti's answer has an SQL statement containing "`<where clause if required>`", no disclaimer "this is pseudo code". Michael's code has "`<conditions here>`" and no disclaimer. Talljoe's answer has "`LIMIT n`" and (whoa!) no disclaimer. Every answer here is not valid SQL, yet you decide that Davood's answer alone deserves a downvote for being pseudo code, and you defend the downvote tooth and nail. Sounds like defensiveness run amok.